# Details view Annotations

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have parsed a KML file and i have placing annotations from file on the map. I have added right button for annotation view, on click which opens a next detail view. The problem is how to send some information (e.g. name or address) to the next view.

Click [here](http://www.megaupload.com/?d=E5FKYU58) for download the template. (i have used example KMLViewer of Apple for parse KML file).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create your own annotation class that keeps track of any data that you might want to be passing along.

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface CHAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSDictionary *someInformation;
    MKMapView *mapView;
}

-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c
                     info:(NSDictionary *)someDictionary
                    title:(NSString *)t 
                subtitle:(NSString *)sub;
@end
```

Then use the `initWithCoordinate` method to create each annotation.
You may also want to include a reference to the mapView in the init method so that you can properly close the annotation from the Annotation object code. Alternatively you can just do a setMapView after creation.

```
- (IBAction) annotationViewClick:(id)sender {
   ...
   [mapView deselectAnnotation:self animated:YES];
   ...
}
```